# Importar bot chatterbot para o telegram

Tags: python, chatbot, telegram-bot, chatterbot

Eu não sei se esse tipo de pergunta é bem vinda aqui, mas vamos lá:

Estou desenvolvendo um chatbot em `python` e escolhi a biblioteca `chatterbot` por causa do `processamento de linguagem natural`, pela capacidade de usar mais de um corpus e principalmente pela capacidade de o bot aprender a conversar com o próprio usuário.

O bot feito com o `chatterbot` roda pelo `CMD`, mas eu gostaria de colocar ele no `telegram`.

Implementei o código da resposta abaixo e por mais que meu chatbot esteja funcionando no computador, no telegram ele não responde as mensagens. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
import os
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters

# Define a função que responderá no Telegram
def response(update, context):
    bot_response = bot.get_response(update.message.text)
    update.message.reply_text(bot_response)

def main():
    # Inicia o bot do Telegram
    updater = Updater("o meu token ta aqui, eu juro")

    # Pega o disparador do Telegram
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # Adiciona a função ao bot
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, response))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

bot = ChatBot("Futaba")

trainer = ListTrainer(bot)

for arquivos in os.listdir('arquivos'):
    chats = open('arquivos/' + arquivos, 'r', encoding="utf8").readlines()
    trainer.train(chats)

print("Hey, meu nome é Futaba e você pode se sentir confortável para conversar comigo mesmo que conversar não seja lá a coisa mais confortável pra você.")
response = bot.get_response("Hey!")
print(response)

while True:
    resq = input('Você: ')
    resp = bot.get_response(resq)
    if float(response.confidence) > 0.5:
        print('Futaba: ' + str(resp))
    else:
        print('Como você tem se sentido?')
```

Comment: Naturalmente que sim. O Chatterbot não define como você obterá a mensagem a ser tratada, então basta você fazer a integração com a API do Telegram e obter as mensagens a partir dela (e enviar a resposta por ela também).

Comment: Aaaah, entendi! Então eu posso continuar usando o chatterbot pra desenvolver o bot, não preciso usar o framework python-telegram-bot, só usar a API mesmo do telegram direto.

Comment: Mas é óbvio que ele não responderá ao Telegram, você nem colocou o bot para ler as mensagens dele. Você leu a documentação citada? Viu que precisa chamar outros métodos além do que eu citei na resposta? Aliás, com a sua edição você invalidou a minha resposta, tanto que você removeu a aceitação, isso deve ser evitado aqui no site e a edição deve ser revertida. Se tem outro problema que não foi abordado aqui você deve abrir uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Ok, cara, era só uma dúvida mas eu já resolvi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O Chatterbot não define a maneira como você vai obter a frase que deverá ser processada, então basta você fazer a integração com a API do Telegram para pegar a frase digitada e responder por ela também.

Por exemplo:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

# Cria uma instância do ChatBot
bot = ChatBot(
    ...
)

# Define a função que responderá no Telegram
def response(update, context):
    bot_response = bot.get_response(update.message.text)
    update.message.reply_text(bot_response)


def main():
    # Inicia o bot do Telegram
    updater = Updater("TOKEN", use_context=True)

    # Pega o disparador do Telegram
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # Adiciona a função ao bot
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, response))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> Códigos (**incompletos**) baseados inteiramente nos exemplos das documentações do [ChatterBot](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#simple-example) e [Telegram](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/echobot2.py)

Assim, quando o bot do Telegram receber uma mensagem, a função `response` será executada passando a frase recebida para o bot do ChatterBot e enviando de volta a resposta obtida.

Comment: Hey, implementei o mesmo código adicionando meu chatbot e incluindo o meu token, porém, o meu chatbot do Telegram não responde as mensagens. Não tem nenhuma mensagem de erro, não tenho ideia do que pode ser.

Comment: Vou adicionar a pergunta o código